# Confused with kmp algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

Can anyone please explain to me... That will kmp algorithm work when the pattern that we are matching does not start with the same letter as the main string...
Eg. String :- abcdbcx
Pattern :- bc
If yes then please explain how.

Answer (score 0):

If the first letter of the string doesn't match the first letter of the pattern, then it moves to the 2nd letter of the string and compares that to the first letter of the pattern.  When there's no initial matching, it acts just like a regular string search.

The difference is when one or more letters of the string match the initial letters of the pattern and then a mismatch is found.  In that case the position in the main string is advanced 1 *from where it already is* and it uses the pre-built table to determine where in the pattern it should reset to.

Comment: Thanks sir, but will you please elaborate the prefixArray finding algorithm..... When we prepare the prefixArray for abcdbcx... What happens then?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh The Wikipedia article describes that in detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Description_of_pseudocode_for_the_search_algorithm

Comment: Note: I have corrected a mistake in the last sentence.